# Pausing execution of embedded IronPython

Tags: c#, debugging, ide, ironpython, breakpoints

I am currently trying to write an IDE with Debugger for IronPython in C#.

I can run the script and get the traceback, but I'm not yet able to pause the script (e.g. at a breakpoint).

Is there a possibility to do so? At least it seems that IronPythonStudio can do this.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pause the IronPython script you will need to stop the traceback function from exiting. When the traceback function exits the script will continue to run.

Harry Pierson wrote a great set of posts on [creating a lightweight IronPython debugger](http://devhawk.net/tag/lightweight-debugger/) which will be a good starting point. He covers pausing the IronPython script in the [Hybrid App Debugging - Threading post](http://devhawk.net/2009/10/08/hybrid-app-debugging-threading/).

IronPythonStudio uses the more heavyweight .NET debugger that is part of Visual Studio and does not use tracebacks.